# Remove unwanted namespaces from child nodes only xsl to transform Filemaker XML for SEPA

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm writing an xsl stylesheet to transform Filemaker xml into Pain.008 xml for SEPA. I'm almost done however I have one problem that I can't seem to find the answer to. The very top level node is  and it needs to look like this:

I have 2 templates that are called from the top level template. The Document tag is opened before and closed after these 2 template calls. If I add the namespace to the Document tag, the top level tag of both of the templates contain an unwanted empty namespace xmlns"". I realise that I am probably not matching the templates correctly but I've tried a few different things to remove these unwanted name spaces now and nothing seems to work. See my stylesheet below and the output.

STYLESHEET(Part of it):

```
<xsl:template match="/">        
      <Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">
          <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>               
              <xsl:call-template name="header"></xsl:call-template>               
              <xsl:call-template name="paymentinf"></xsl:call-template>
          </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
      </Document>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- Header template -->
<xsl:template name="header"  >
    <GrpHdr>
        <MsgId>
            <xsl:value-of select="fm:FMPXMLRESULT/fm:RESULTSET/fm:ROW[1]/fm:COL[$MsgId]/fm:DATA"/>
        </MsgId>           
        <CreDtTm>
            <xsl:value-of select="fm:FMPXMLRESULT/fm:RESULTSET/fm:ROW[1]/fm:COL[$CreDtTm]/fm:DATA"/>
        </CreDtTm>         
        <NbOfTxs>
            <xsl:value-of select="fm:FMPXMLRESULT/fm:RESULTSET/fm:ROW[1]/fm:COL[$NbOfTxs]/fm:DATA"/>
        </NbOfTxs>          
        <CtrlSum>
            <xsl:value-of select="fm:FMPXMLRESULT/fm:RESULTSET/fm:ROW[1]/fm:COL[$CtrlSum]/fm:DATA"/>
        </CtrlSum>

        <InitgPty>
            <Id>
                <OrgId>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>
                            <xsl:value-of select="fm:FMPXMLRESULT/fm:RESULTSET/fm:ROW[1]/fm:COL[$Id]/fm:DATA"/>
                        </Id>
                    </Othr>
                </OrgId>
            </Id>
        </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
 </xsl:template>
```

Output: (Only the important part)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
 "xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">
<CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
<GrpHdr xmlns="">
<MsgId>17</MsgId>
<CreDtTm>2013-11-04T15:43:14</CreDtTm>
<NbOfTxs>6</NbOfTxs>
<CtrlSum>6203.6</CtrlSum>
<InitgPty>
<Id>
<OrgId>
<Othr>
<Id>IE14SDD360038</Id>
</Othr>
</OrgId>
</Id>
</InitgPty>
</GrpHdr>
<PmtInf xmlns="">
```

Desired Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
     "xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">
    <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
    <MsgId>17</MsgId>
    <CreDtTm>2013-11-04T15:43:14</CreDtTm>
    <NbOfTxs>6</NbOfTxs>
    <CtrlSum>6203.6</CtrlSum>
    <InitgPty>
    <Id>
    <OrgId>
    <Othr>
    <Id>IE14SDD360038</Id>
    </Othr>
    </OrgId>
    </Id>
    </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
    <PmtInf>
```

Comment: Hard to understand what exactly do you want to achieve.
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"> is ok for you and you want <GrpHdr xmlns=""> to be just <GrpHdr>?

Comment: Sorry yes that is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: I would like the output to be Document xmlns ="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"> <GrpHdr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add needed namespaces in templates to `<GrpHdr>` as you did for `<Document>`

e.g.

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">
<GrpHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">
```

It will be valid XML and repeated namespace declaration doesn't affect logical structure and is ignored by any valid parser.

Comment: OK duh! I've just tried that and its perfect! I thought that if I did that then GrpHdr would have that namespace too! Thank you so much